# How to group terms with the same exponential factor together after Expand?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

```
ET[t] := 
  E1*Exp[-I*w1*t] + E2*Exp[-I*w2*t] + E3*Exp[-I*w3*t] + 
   E1*Exp[I*w1*t] + E2*Exp[I*w2*t] + E3*Exp[I*w3*t];
THGExp[t] = ET[t]*ET[t]*ET[t]//Expand;
```

I want to group terms in THGExp[t] with the same exponential together. But I don't know exactly how should I do this? Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Try `Collect[#,Exp[_],Simplify]&`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "GroupB" and a function that extracts the exponent:

```
(# /. ___ Exp[e_] -> e) &
```

With this:

```
GatherBy[List @@ THGExp[t], (# /. ___ Exp[e_] -> e) &]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn the comment to an answer:

```
Collect[THGExp[t], Exp[_], Simplify]
```